# Combining Project Lists in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007, project-management, collaboration

I am looking for a way to combine several project lists in SharePoint so that I can display all open tasks associated with any project in one table and have a Gantt chart reflecting the same.

Any other suggestions for keeping track of a team of project managers are more than welcome!

Thanks,

Karl

Answer (score 0):

I went to great lengths to prototype a PM like tool using three (3) Lists: Projects, Deliverables and Tasks. Long story is below, **short version**... if you looking for a complex PM solution (say 10 projects, with 5 deliverables per project, and 10 tasks per deliverables) with dependencies, I would try to buy an external SharePoint plugin. The issue is I haven't found a way to create dependencies. So if you get a request for a high priority project, you insert your new project, it won't push out the other items. We are looking into  some of these SharePoint plugins, but nothing concrete yet.

---

**Long Story**... I created a page, with the 3 web part being those lists, and using connections, I tied the lists together to filter down. That work pretty well, but again the issue is the lack of dependencies and being able to easily shift projects/deliverables/tasks.

Comment: Hi ViperForce, thanks for your response. I have been looking at various plugins to carry out what I want to achieve but my budget probably won't stretch to obtain them. When you say "tied the lists together": did you achieve this through an spsitedataquery? Because this is an option I have been looking into since finding it online. Unfortunately I cannot find a decent example of someone using this in CAML, which is what I am using on my site. I was thinking of doing something like you did, simply having all of my lists on one page and seperate gantt charts, but this isn't a very pretty option!